# NSUserNotification close calls didActivateNotification

Tags: objective-c, nsusernotification, nsusernotificationcenter

Since MacOS 10.13 everytime I click the close button on a `NSUserNotification` it calls:

```
- (void) userNotificationCenter:(NSUserNotificationCenter *)center didActivateNotification:(NSUserNotification *)notification
```

How can I prevent this or handle the `close` vs the `action` button

To create the notification I do:

```
NSUserNotification *notification = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init];
...
[notification setHasActionButton:false];
[[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] deliverNotification:notification];
[[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] setDelegate:(id)self];
```

and `NSUserNotificationAlertStyle` in the `.plist` is set to "`alert`"

but now basically the close button reacts the same way the `actionButton` does??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSUserNotification has property from which you can manage notification identifier or hasActionButton value, so you can handle the close vs the action button with if else in the same delegate method

```
- (void) userNotificationCenter:(NSUserNotificationCenter *)center didActivateNotification:(NSUserNotification *)notification{    
}
```

Comment: What is the property?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsusernotification?language=objc here you will get the property detail which you can use and write the conditional action.

Answer (score 1):

This is works for me..

you can remove notification in `didActivateNotification:` method

```
- (void) userNotificationCenter:(NSUserNotificationCenter *)center didActivateNotification:(NSUserNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Notification - Clicked");
    [center removeDeliveredNotification: notification];
    notification=nil;
}
```

where `center` is...

```
NSUserNotificationCenter *center = [NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter];
    [center scheduleNotification:notification];
```